# How do i tell my custom bootloader to run my kernel

Tags: assembly, kernel, bootloader

I'm very new to assembly coding and have been having a very hard time googling what I need to know, All i want to know is

1) where and how do i put my kernel in a floppy file ( .flp ) along side my bootloader

2) how to I tell my bootloader to run the kernel

I have everything written i just can't seem to attach the files and tell my bootloader to run the kernel

EDIT: I'm using nasm to make the .bin files then renaming the .bin file to .flp then using rufus to load my .flp image to a usb flash drive with the DD option

Comment: Why do you code your *custom* bootloader (not so easy with [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) and boring to code for older BIOSes)? [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) is so convenient! See [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/) wiki.

Comment: i know using grub would be a lot easier, i just want to understand how it works and i feel that making a very simple one would help me a lot more

Comment: Current PCs often have UEFI. I would recommend studying the source code of GRUB and concentrate your efforts on coding your kernel. Life is short and current bootloaders are not that simple!

Comment: it would be very hard to study the source code for grub since i barely understand assembly and I'm slowly learning the all of the int command uses, conditions and eveything else that comes with assembly

Comment: Then concentrate your efforts on learning assembly and coding your tiny kernel. This would need a year of work at least. Coding a bootloader is complex  (because PC hardware and firmware are complex!) , and won't teach you much. BTW, `int` commands are BIOS related (and UEFI works differently); or code directly an UEFI kernel. BIOS is obsolete.

Comment: I know it would be a lot simpler but I'm working on a very basic msdos/mikeOS like operating system, i know it would take a while but i would like to know that i created eveything from scratch instead of putting a bunch of other peoples code together and calling the random combination mine.

Comment: Still, start first by coding your kernel (it would take years and would teach you many things, and you could get bored before having it working). Once you are satisfied with it, consider coding a bootloader (which is different with UEFI and with BIOS). Don't spend months of work on the bootloader before having a running kernel.

Comment: Well then how would i test my kernel, i currently use qemu-system-i386 for testing before moving it over to my mini laptop on a usb

Comment: BTW, all of your questions are answered on [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/) and your question is too broad for SO. Answering it in full would require an entire book. Read also [Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) - a freely downloadable textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might think Basile's comments somewhat dismissive, but the fact is, even though your question is very specific, the combinations and permutations of solutions are not. The first thing to know would be, what does your kernel expect. In my case, my boot loader;

- Creates a stack frame just below EBDA
- Reads E820 map
- Enables A20
- Reads as many sectors as will fit between 1000H and SS:0
- Enters protected mode

So the last thing coded in boot sector is

```
        cli                     ; No more interrupts
        lgdt     [cs:GDTR]      ; Load GDT register
        mov      eax, cr0
         or      al, 0x01       ; Set protected mode bit
        mov      cr0, eax
        jmp      8:0x8060
```

and the first thing in kernel

```
      mov   ecx, ss     ; Get stack segment
      shl   ecx, 4  
      add   ebp, ecx    ; SS:BP becomes EBP
      add   esp, ecx    ; SS:SP becomes ESP

; Initialize segments to point to data area

      mov   eax, 16
      mov    es, ax
      mov    ds, ax
      mov    ss, ax
      mov    fs, ax
      mov    gs, ax
```

This solution is pedicated entriely on my design critera and I would venture to say, your not going to find another coder that has done it exaclty like this. Ultimately though, I've done exacly as you, created an image and copied it to USB using `dd if=Proto of=/dev/sdc`. The file called `Proto` is a binary image used in Bochs.

To get any meaningful input from anyone, you'll need to be very specific about expectations and needs and it all begins with seeing what your custom bootloader looks like.

Comment: `; Convert to absolute value` is a confusing comment because "absolute value" already has a well-defined meaning that is different from what you mean. Maybe "absolute address" would be better? (Oh wait, I'm not on Code Review!)

Comment: @CodyGray Coincidentally, when I wrote that comment, that had crossed my mind, as SS:SP is every bit as absolute as ESP. Probably what would have been better to comment the four instructions collectively as `convert the segmented pointers to 32 bit`.